# preposition choice: refill of or on?

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know whether "of" or "on" should be used in the following in a restaurant setting:

> Do you offer free refills **of** / **on** coffee?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: **....free coffee refills?** would work just as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Both](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22free%20refills%20on%20coffee%22&oq=%22free%20refills%20on%20coffee%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.8995j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) [prepositions](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&ei=NN4sXKa0Hsjk_Ab0-ICIDA&q=%22free%20refills%20of%20coffee%22&oq=%22free%20refills%20of%20coffee%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i7i30l3j0i30.63725.63725..65287...0.0..0.64.64.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.DT4624OMaO0) are grammatical.

The prepositions can have slightly different meanings, although not every speaker may employ the distinction.

***on*** coffee refers to coffee not as beverage but as (menu) offering, that is, as item for sale.

***of*** coffee refers to coffee as beverage, something that can be dispensed into your cup.

You're familiar no doubt with **of** (cup of coffee) and don't need examples.

> There's a holiday sale **on** helmets at BikesBikesBikesBikesBikes.com

With **on**, "Free refills" is cast as retail incentive analogous to "discount".

And thus **on** can be understood as "applied to" in its figurative, not its sticky literal sense.